# Camtasia recording of recording fails to capture switch from PPT to Word

Tags: google-chrome, video, camtasia

I'm using Camtasia to record a recording. The original recording is an Adobe Connect file that consists of interleaved PPT slides and Word files. So the narrator shows a PPT slide, then switches to Word, then back to PPT.

While recording with Camtasia, everything appears to be fine. But upon rendering, instead of seeing the back-and-forth between PPT and Word, the video is stuck on the PPT.

The audio has no problems.

Anyone know why the problem happens and how to prevent it?

If it helps inform an answer, then here are some more details:

- Camtasia 7
- File rendered as an MP4
- Windows 10 Home
- Chrome version 51
- Ad blocker on
- Screen saver on

Answer (score 0):

Several times now this week I gave it another try and was successful each time by doing the following:

1. I paused AdGuard. (Usually I leave it on.)
2. When the capture was finished, I played the camrec file back from beginning to end. (Usually I go directly to production.)
3. After playing back the camrec file, I created a project. (Usually I skip projects.)
4. After creating the project, I produced the MP4.